# @media for 2 different resolutions

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have this line in CSS:

```
icons span{
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
margin-left: -3px;
```

and then

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){
.icons span{
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

Now I would like to set margin-left:6px again for width 991px and under? How do I do that in this example?

Comment: Tip: You can add multiple `@media` blocks.

Comment: I've tried this as suggested below and doesn't work.

Comment: your demo works fine for me (Chrome 31)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure if i understand that right. You want 6px margin left up to 991px and than -3px up to 1200px and than the 6px again? If so i wold do it like the following CSS.

```
.icons span {
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   margin-left: 6px;
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
 .icons span {
    margin-left: -3px;
  }
}


@media (min-width:  1200px){
 .icons span{
    margin-left: 6px;
  }
}
```

or short:

```
@media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .icons span{
    margin-left: -3px;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I did a Demo for You. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/tZS46/)

Comment: I've tried all of this already and for some reason it keeps displaying  -3 for everything below 1200

Comment: EDIT: Wait, your first media just talks to the class .icon, but your class is called .os-icon

Answer (score 2):

You could add more media to your css.
try to add this after your media

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
.os-icons span{
  margin-left: 6px;
}
```

If you wanna use an OR condition you ca use a comma separator to specify that like this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px), (max-width: 991px){
    .os-icons span{
      margin-left: 6px;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I've tried both of these already and for some reason this isn't working correctly and I have no idea why. When I'm resizing window and checking live code, the margin is always at -3 for everything below 1200.

Comment: try to resize page and refreshit to see if works fine @user3187469

Comment: have seen your jsfiddle change the class name to os-icons please and try @user3187469

Answer (score 0):

You can separate rules with `,` .

```
 @media (min-width: 1200px), (min-width: 991px){
    .icons span{
      margin-left: 6px;
     }
 }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries#comma-separated_lists